# How to assign multiple IP addresses to a single computer?

Tags: networking, ip, dhcp

The dhcp ip range is 192.168.0.255/24. I wanted my computer to get multiple ip addresses from this dhcp. So I can have multiple connections through different ip addresses with just a single computer!

is there anyway to do that?

Edit1:

In Windows or Unix, doesn't matter!

Suppose that I want to download a file. The very simple thing that a downloader does is to split the file to some parts and download them simultaneously! so that it should connect to the file server through many connections (1 connection for each part). Here, I want the downloader to establish each connection with a different IP address!

Actually, the server has limited the download speed for IP addresses. So, this way I will bypass this download limit!

Comment: Superuser.com or serverfault.com would likley give you better suggestions.

Comment: You really need to state what OS you want to do this with

Comment: Why do you want to do that? In Linux you can assign several IP addresses to the same network interface, but I doubt you can convince DHCP to hand them out...

Comment: What do you mean that you want "multiple connections"?

Comment: That won't help your speed. The number one method of speeding up a download is to pay your ISP for a faster connection/go somewhere that has a faster connection.

Comment: Typically web browsers defaults (and almost every other application) to the default IP address/network interface.  Having multiple IP address won't do you any good unless you have applications that you can select what IP address it uses.

In your case you might want a virtual machine, possibly used with a proxy that would show externally as you having a diff. IP.

Answer (score 13):

Giving yourself multiple IP addresses on your local network won't do anything to get around a download limit.

Your addresses are in the `192.168.0.0/16` range. This range consists of private IP addresses, which have no meaning outside your LAN. Your router uses a system called Network Address Translation (NAT) to let every device on your home network use the same public IP. The reason for this is that there are fewer IPv4 addresses than are needed, and this system allows a house to share a single address.

Because your router is using NAT, the download server doesn't see your private IP. As far as it's concerned, *any* device in your house uses the same IP, so it will consider them to be the same device.

The only real solution would be to buy additional public IPs. However, this isn't something you're likely to find on a consumer internet connection. Generally, only servers need public IPs, so you'd likely find them only on a business-grade connection.

Summary: While you *can* give yourself multiple IPs (statically, if necessary), it won't help with your actual problem.

Comment: I completely understood your answer, but it seems that I couldn't state my question clearly. anyway thanks! But assume the IP range is something else, for example, 213.233.170.0/16 (it's the IP range of public Wi-Fi in a university). now how con you get multiple addresses?

Comment: Basically?  One can't.  IP addresses are assigned by a DHCP server outside of the user's control, and granted based on hardware addresses.  The only way would be to add extra wireless interfaces (wi-fi cards, USB dongles, &c), and run different addresses on each one.

Answer (score 6):

Answering the asked question ([unrelated](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6271/user-asks-for-answer-that-wont-solve-their-problem) to the problem asker does have):

To get multiple IPs from DHCP server, you need to add new real or virtual Ethernet adapter with separate MAC address.

Example for GNU/Linux (not tested):

```
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth0
ip link add type veth
brctl addif br0 veth0
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 up
ifconfig veth0 up
ifconfig veth1 up
ifconfig br0 up
dhclient br0 veth1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a virtual computers inside one computer. Then you can assign different IP Adresses.

Comment: or you can install another network adapter to your computer and assign another ip address as in [multihoming](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/tcpip/g/multihoming.htm)

Comment: That seems good. but is there another easy way? because in order to do that I have to run several VMwares! but I wanted to do it automatically.